# Key/Value Confusion in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This code does what it's supposed to do. My hang up is understanding what the key in a dictionary is and what the value is. I was (~still am) sure it was -- dict = {key : value} -- But upon running the code below it appears to be the opposite. Can someone put my mind to rest and clarify what I'm missing. I don't want to move on without thoroughly understanding it. Thanks.

```
prices = {
"banana" : 4,
"apple"  : 2,
"orange" : 1.5,
"pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
"banana" : 6,
"apple"  : 0,
"orange" : 32,
"pear"   : 15,
}

total = 0
for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
    total = total + prices[key]*stock[key]
print

print total
```

output:

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32

pear
price: 3
stock: 15

banana
price: 4
stock: 6

apple
price: 2
stock: 0

117.0
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, it is {key: value} and your code backs that up.

```
for key in prices:  # iterates through the keys of prices ["orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"] (though no ordering is guaranteed)
    print key # prints "orange"

    print "price: %s" % prices[key] # prints prices["orange"] (1.5) 
    # which means it prints the value of the prices dict, orange key.

    print "stock: %s" % stock[key] # prints stock["orange"] (32) 
    #which means it prints the value of the stock dict, orange key.
```

This is doing exactly what you should expect it to do.  Where is your confusion (ie. Where does it seem to behave the opposite of what you described)?

Comment: Right, it did exactly what I wanted it to. Through trial and error I got the code to work but I wanted a better understanding of why it worked. 

Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a dictionary as a city street. The keys are the address, a value is what is at a particular address:

```
from pprint import pprint
first_street = {
    100: 'some house',
    101: 'some other house'
}
pprint(first_street)
```

The addresses do not have to be numbers, they can be any immutable data type, int, string, tuple, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - dicts contains pairs of `key: value` (in that order). Maybe you are confused, that key can be any immutable type.
I would recommend you to walk through a documentation on that topic: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict